# RobotFramework Print Time to Log

Tags: robotframework, bdd

I have tried putting this into my keywords

```
Date and time
${CurrentDate}    Get Current Date    result_format=%d-%m-%Y
Log    ${CurrentDate}
```

but to no success.

I have multiple test cases in my test suite and I want to print out time when each test case is run. I will do this probably in the Test Setup.

Comment: The log file contains the begin and end timestamps for literally everything by default. Do you want to log it onto the console maybe?

Answer (score 1):

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation     A test suite with a single test for valid login.
Library    DateTime 

*** Test Cases ***
Valid Login
    ${CurrentDate}    Get Current Date    result_format=%d-%m-%Y
    Log    ${CurrentDate}
```

Your code works

[image]